# Rails 5: do not allow create action if params are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this Controller, where I can create User Group and add Users, Roles to it:

```
class Strongbolt::UserGroupsController < ApplicationController
# some code...

def create
  user_roles #Helper method
  respond_to do |format|
  if @user_group = Strongbolt::UserGroup.create!(user_group_params)
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "User group #{@user_group.name} created!" }
  else
    format.json { render json: @user_group.errors.full_messages,
                          status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# some code...

def user_group_params
  params.require(:strongbolt_user_group)
        .permit(:name, :description, {user_ids: []}, {role_ids: []})
end
```

**If `user_ids` and `role_ids` are empty, I need to do some error or stop Create action - I do not need User Group without at least one user and role. How do I do that, please?**

Since this is related to [Strongbolt gem](https://github.com/605data/strongbolt) where related Models are inside it, I cannot do validation on model side - I have to do it in Controller. At the moment this functionality is not there, so I have to add that for my project.

So far I've been trying to do something related tho this:

`redirect_to 'new' unless params[:user_ids].present?`

Update

Here is part of my Form:

```
<!-- Users tab -->
<div class="tab-pane" id="users">
  <div class="i-checks">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, @users_for_group, :id, :name) do |b| %>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <%= b.check_box %>
      </div>
        <%= b.label %><br><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Roles tab -->
  <div class="tab-pane" id="roles">
    <div class="i-checks">
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:role_ids, @roles, :id, :name) do |bb| %>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <%= bb.check_box %>
        </div>
          <%= bb.label %><br><br>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update 2**

```
  def create
    user_roles #Helper method
    respond_to do |format|
      unless params[:user_ids].blank? || params[:role_ids].blank?
        @user_group = Strongbolt::UserGroup.create!(user_group_params)
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "User group #{@user_group.name} created!" }
      else
        format.json {
          render json: @user_group.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
        }
        format.js { flash.now[:error] = "User group was not created!" }
      end
    end
  end
```

In terminal I see this:

```
Started POST "/en/strongbolt/user_groups" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-06-06 17:51:59 +0000
Processing by Strongbolt::UserGroupsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "strongbolt_user_group"=>{"name"=>"Test @Jun6 v2", "description"=>"test", "user_ids"=>["", "5"], "role_ids"=>["", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Create User Group", "locale"=>"en"}
```

**The Solution**

First of all it appears `collection_check_boxes` by default include hidden value " ", so I had to remove that with something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:role_ids, @roles, :id, :name, include_hidden: false) do |bb| %>
```

If not to remove hidden field, Rails will not check empty params as basically params are there.

Then I was able to implement this:

```
before_action :validate_presence, only: [:create]

def check_presence
  params[:strongbolt_user_group][:user_ids].present? &&
  params[:strongbolt_user_group][:role_ids].present?
end

def validate_presence
  if !check_presence
    render json: { error: {
        message: "Bad Request, parameters missing.",
        status: 500 }
    }
  end
end
```

I had to include Model name to check params presence, otherwise it did not work. Now I can implement JS part where I show some messages that something can't be blank, etc., but that is different story. Now my Controller will not accept empty params in this special case with Strongbolt gem.

Comment: Have you considered use `save` instead `create!`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I can use `save`, but how then I would do validation, please?

Comment: It'll be very ugly to do it in the controller, but at least you can elaborate a logic to validate when such params are `nil`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I agree it is ugly to do it in Controller, however I need some workaround to keep moving. As I mentioned this part of functionality is not in the gem, so I need some solution. I believe this will not be the most heavy used part of my app.

Comment: You could re-open the class in the gem and add the validation, but I would consider the downsides to this.

Comment: @Kris Sure, editing the gem code was one option I considered, however I could appear in trouble if there are major changes in the gem's code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a validation. Read about them here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

`validates :name_of_attribute, presence: true`

You can also prevent submission via js. If you're using erb it would look something like this:

`<%= f.text_field, :name_of_attribute, required: true %>`

This will prevent submission if the field is empty.

If you want to do it completely in the controller, write a method that checks presence of those fields you want and add a flash message instead of saving if those fields are blank.

You could optionally disable submit with javascript if at least one of those fields isn't selected. (or both)

Update on how to check for blank values. Blank will return true when an array is empty, empty string, nil values, etc. https://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F

```
unless params[:user_ids].blank? || params[:role_ids].blank?
   # call to your create method
else 
   # show the user an error message
end
```

Comment: *I cannot do validation on model side - I have to do it in Controller*

Comment: I know, but I can't do in Model as they are in Strongbolt gem. Is there any other way, please?

Comment: ah--what type of form field is it?

Comment: You could also add `required: true` to an erb form...it will prevent them from submitting via js.

Comment: It is check boxes - please, see above in Update. Yes, I know I can do it required in View, however I'm not sure if this is enough, so I thought maybe I need to have some Controller validation instead.

Comment: I could write a method, however I stuck a bit on that validation part. Would it be something like `params[:user_ids].present?` Some example would help me a lot.

Comment: updated. the inverse (if present?) would work fine, too.

Comment: Thank you. I try to implement it, however my code in Update 2 above does not seem to be working now - it does not create anything. Can you check it, please?

Comment: It doesn't create everything even when that condition returns true? Could you (1) post the params coming through in the stack trace? and (2) log something out in the unless `p "inside unless"` and in the else p `"inside the else"`. It's possible that the params aren't coming through as `params[:user_ids]` but are structured some other way.

Comment: log something out in each condition so we can see where it's failing. Should be more to that stack trace, too. It should either show you that the object got created or show you errors.

Comment: I think I got it working - see in the solution above.

Comment: that's exactly what I initially told you to do. glad you got it working.